# The custom client-side validation(attribute) doesn't trigger in MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I write a code for validate the incoming data.

All of the **built-in validation** (RequiredAttribute etc) are **works**...

**But my own** writed DateRangeAttribute **doesnt triggers errors on post**, and the post is comes to my controller :(.

The **overrided IsValid** method sends back the **good(false)**  value, and on the server side the controller see correctly the Invalid ModelState, but the client side not.

*The data validation attributes are rendered to HTML on the browser:*

**I would like the avoid the post until all of the data are realy valid.**

## There is the Code:

**DateRangeAttribute**

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        public DateRangeAttribute (string minimumYear) 
            :base(typeof(DateTime), minimumYear, DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
        {
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var inputYear = value as int?;
            var result = (inputYear != null && inputYear >= 1886 && inputYear <= DateTime.Now.Year);

            return result ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            return "The year must be greater than 1886 and lower than the actual year.";
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format(GetErrorMessage(), name);
        }
    }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ... -->

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Car", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateForm" }))
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <!-- ... -->
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
    <!-- ... -->
}

Web.Config file:
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- ... -->
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to provide a custom client side validation implementation thru `IClientValidatable`. And because of that, I suggest that you inherit from ValidationAttribute directly since you will have to change almost everything anyway

Comment: I did everthing exactly as in the following video, but i didnt get the error messages: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcX8WW4fL1s

Comment: That video taught a lot of wrong things 1) the minimum year is hardcoded so it may not be parsed properly when you internationalize your app (some cultures use MM/DD/YYYY while others use DD/MM/YYYY) 2) A DateRangeAttribute instance is created per property then reused in subsequent requests so the max value will be the time when the first submission was made. Lastly, the author mentioned in his [blog post](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.sg/2013/08/part-81-range-attribute-in-aspnet-mvc.html) that the client validation doesn't work and will be discussed in a later video session

Comment: Oh, i See. But how triggered their events on client side? Cheat time? :) Can you link me a small tut about your idea?

Comment: There are samples on the web. Like [this](http://www.headspringlabs.com/blog/mvc-custom-unobtrusive-validator-attribute-date-range-validation/) just modify it a little bit to your need